# Hibernate mapping many to one with condition

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have two tables, a user table and an address table. A user has many addresses. But the address has a column that says is primary or not:

```
User table: Id,Name
Address table: Id, fkUserId, AddressLine,isPrimary
```

I want to have in my hbm an user class, for the table User, with just the primary address, but I don't know how to set the Address class in the user mapping with the condition ("filter" by the fkUserId and isPrimary=true

Someone knows how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Filters. Refer the documentation here

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html

Some examples in following link

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/

Comment: I want reuse this class inside one other class in the mapping. If I use filter I will need to turn on the filter every time right?